# Specifying a slopes-as-outcomes model in R

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

I have read some of the other threads and wanted to check my understanding of exactly what I am asking R to do. My code is:

The slopes-as-outcomes multilevel model i wish to test is:

Level 1: WPMSP = b0j + b1j (WPSE)+ rij

Level 2:

b0j = γ00 + γ01 (ROVER) + γ02 (BPSE) + u0j

b1j = γ10 + γ11 (ROVER) + uij

The slopes-as-outcomes model i wish to test is whether WPMSP varies dependent on a 3 way interaction between WPSE, BPSE, and ROVER. This is my code:

lmer(WPMSP ~ WPSE * BPSE * ROVER + (1 + WPSE) + (1|WPSE:BPSE) + (1|WPSE:BPSE:ROVER), data = PhD)

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit to clarify what you mean by the slope and intercept of WPMSP?

Comment: I have edited to show the multilevel equation that I want to test in R. Hopefully this helps to clarify it. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to fit a much simpler, more interpretable model. As far as syntax, your `lmer` model is incorrect. For a random intercepts model, the random effect is `(1|id)` where `id` is the cluster level indicator, not a fixed effect.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Adam. My theory suggests a three-way interaction should change the relationship with the DV, and this slopes-as-outcomes was used to test it by a different author. The only way I could simplify it is to turn one or two continuous variables into categorical If you know of a better way to test such a theory that would be great. RE the latter part of your comment, for testing a slopes-as-outcomes model only, how should this be coded? Many thanks for your help.